# Apache Camel Context start failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am pretty new to Spring Boot, Apache Camel and the ActiveMQ broker. I am trying to create an application which will send a message to a queue which I am hosting locally using Camel for routing.

**POM:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-activemq</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**MsgRouteBuilder:**

```java
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:firstRoute")
    .setBody(constant("Hello"))
    .to("activemq:queue:myQueue");
}
```

**application.yaml:**

```
activemq:
    broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616
    user: meAd
    password: meAd
```

**MainApp.java:**

```java
package me.ad.myCamel;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

import me.ad.myCamel.router.MessageRouteBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableCaching
public class MeAdApp implements CommandLineRunner {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MeAdApp.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      SpringApplication.run(MeAdApp.class, args);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Starting MeAdApp...");
  }  
}
```

**MyController.java :**

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/routing")
public boolean sendToMyQueue() {
    sendMyInfo.startRouting();
    return true;
}
```

**SendMyInfo.java :**

```java
MsgRouteBuilder routeBuilder = new MsgRouteBuilder();
CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();


public void startRouting(){

    try {
        ctx.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
        ctx.start();
        Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
        ctx.stop();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So, whenever I call my rest end point: `/routing`, I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/RuntimeException;`
```

Can anybody please point me to the right direction as to why I am getting this error? Any help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: You should not mix Camel v2 and v3 JARs in the same application. Use only one version and the same version of Apache Camel.

Comment: @ClausIbsen  So can I remove the came core 2.22.0 from the set up ?

Comment: @ClausIbsen Removing Camel core gives camel component not present issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the components of the same version. If you are using camel-core with 3.2.0, use camel-activemq 3.2.0. And, since you are using spring-boot, you can make use of the starter dependencies. Just add these and you are good to go.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-activemq-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```